# Difference between t.change and change_column in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new in learning ruby on rails, I am confused when to use change_column and when to use t.change for migrations?

For example

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
   def change
     create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps
     end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Do you have an example for `t.change`? I have not come across this method

Comment: @Ankit 
`class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `def change` method is part of all migrations. This method contains the changes that you want to apply during a given migration.

All your migrations will either have `change` method or an `up` and `down` method. If you define a `change` method like this:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
   def change
     create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps
     end
   end
 end
```

then when you apply this migration, a table will be created, and when you roll back this migration, Rails will try to generate a reverse of the migration. In this case, the reverse of `create_table` would be to drop the table.

Now suppose you already have this table created, but then you realize that you want to limit the length of the `name` field, then you can generate a migration to do that. This migration will use `change_column` method because you are now trying to change the definition of an existing column.

```
class LimitProductName < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
   def change
     change_column :products, :name, :string, limit: 100
   end
 end
```